# Can we create energy from nothing?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

Energy came from nothing as many scientists know. So, is it possible to create energy from nothing and break the laws of physics.

Comment: "Energy came from nothing" is simply untrue, unless by "nothing" one means "an unusual kind of thing, such as quantum fields in a low energy state combined with gravitation".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't. When studying the transfer of energy in nature, we have found that very strict book-keeping rules apply always and forever. These rules are called *conservation laws* and in the universe we happen to inhabit, there is no way to break them, and when it appears that they are broken what it really means is that something is wrong with the way we are doing the book keeping.

The conservation of energy in all processes in our universe is rooted mathematically in the fact that the laws of nature do not change with time. If we could turn off one physical law or another at a chosen point in time, magic would become possible; the absence of magic is a good indication that energy is conserved- and that it cannot be created out of nothing.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei, thanks for that. this answer is a condensed version of an essay I wrote a couple of years ago,

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no. Energy didn't come "from nothing". Since the big bang is an observational event horizon, we cannot talk about any events earlier, so one assumes that all the energy and matter has always been contained in your universe.

And even if one were to consider the initial energy to have come from nothing, the first law of thermodynamics or the law of conservation of energy states that

> the total energy of an isolated system is constant; energy can be transformed from one form to another, but can be neither created nor destroyed

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics))

So now, we cannot create energy. In addition, if one were to "break" the laws of physics, they wouldn't be considered laws.

Answer (score -3):

I understand your reasoning but say there was really nothing before the big bang, then something must have come from that. Like the empty space in an atom. I was thinking maybe there is another type of energy store that we didn't know about yet, one that comes from nothing. the nothingness stores the energy and then it condensed due to space-time until the big bang happened because of it becoming too big and imploding. I do find it interesting. All I'm saying is that maybe the anti-matter caused some kind of energy transfer that is completely new to us.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please notice that [we deal with mainstream Physics in this website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4539/168783), meaning we are interested in answers which have already been well-developed and widely accepted by the scientific community. But don't let this discourage you! We can't wait to have you around once you are a little bit older and more familiar with the math =)